# Permissions per folder in samba share

Tags: samba

I need to create a public share where there is a folder public and folder user such as everyone (including guests) have full access to public and for user only the specific user has full access but everyone else have Read and Execute permissions.

this is my share configuration.

```
[public]
  comment = public storage
  path = /home/shares/public
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  browsable = yes
```

Thanks.